# Changing PSPDFKit view mode

Tags: ios, pspdfkit

I'm using PSPDFKit. The only mode I can show the pages is single. I'm wondering if it is possible to show two pages with when the device is in landscape position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating view controller for PSPDFKit using PSPDFView controller. make the page mode Automatic.
It must be something like this:

```
PSPDFViewController *pdfController = [[PSPDFViewController alloc] initWithDocument:pdfDocument];
pdfController.pageMode = PSPDFPageModeAutomatic;
```